# Are 90 minutes layover in Munich Airport and 120 minutes in Heathrow airport enough?

Tags: layovers, lhr, short-connections, muc

I will be traveling from Delhi to San Francisco via route DEL - MUC - LHR - SFO. 
There are  connecting Lufthansa flights from DEL to SFO. Layover time at MUC is 90 minutes and at LHR is 120 minutes. I will land at MUC at 5:30 AM and at LHR at 10:30 AM. 
I guess it's single ticket as I bought it from Expedia and its a part of 2-way journey. I hold a US visa and an Indian passport.

Are the layover periods enough for boarding at both places?

Comment: this is better as two questions. Each should contain whether this is a single ticket (bought all at once from one airline) and your citizenship, since it affects what lines you go in. **That said** I think we already have good answers to both.

Comment: for Munich: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/12765/is-1%c2%bd-hours-enough-for-a-transit-at-munich-airport?rq=1

Comment: for LHR: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66959/is-one-hour-between-connecting-flights-at-heathrow-terminal-5-enough

Comment: Are you booked on a single ticket? If so, then it is the airline's responsibility. They have to book you a ticket with enough time for the transit/transfer window.

Comment: As long as it was bought as a single ticket, there are plenty of flights between MUC and LHR and LHR and SFO. The airline will rebook you if you miss a connection. To be honest, with that itinerary, I'd be quite glad to miss a connection!

Comment: Another important piece of information is whether you need to change terminals at Heathrow. (By the way, don't say "London Airport" -- there's no airport called literally that, and London is served by Heathrow, Gatwick, Stansted, Luton and London City, plus a number of smaller airports such as Southend.)

Comment: This should be quite fine. Lufthansa does operate a direct flight from MUC to SFO, but I presume this itinerary was cheaper or otherwise better for you (after all, Air India has a nonstop now from DEL-SFO if you wanted that).

Comment: Hey Kumar - for the Heathrow one, you have to state WHICH TERMINALS you arrive-depart.   For Munich it's no problem.  BTW - India .. SF ... I'll take one guess: you're exceptionally good at at least two major programming languages  ;)

Answer (score -4):

(1) Namaste, Berwyn's comment is very astute: on such a long flight, super-popular routes: it will be kind of "normal" if you miss a connection, and it won't matter at all, they'll just put you on another.  Your flight is so long you won't even notice if you arrive the odd day after the supposed original arrival time

(2) For Munich no problem

(3) For LHR you must state your arrival/departure terminals

At Heathrow - the most horrific, sickening, soul-destroying anything in the solar system - transfers are often a marthon

(4) Thank God, you **DID** book on one complete ticket with one airline (right?)  You have nothing to worry about, they'll just put you on a next flight if there's a screw-up.

Tip: pick aisle seats

(5) the food is crap on Lufthansa's India->Frankfort legs :/

(6) You should have flown Emirates dude.  It's not even more expensive.

If a corporate travel department booked this disaster, you got screwed :/  I'm sorry.